# Copying Range from Excel to Powerpoint and change alignment with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a range from Excel into PowerPoint using vba.
Copying and Pasting are no Problem, but i can´t get the text in the created PowerPoint table to be aligned right (and vertical Center).

Here is the part how i copy and paste the range:

```
Dim myWks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide


wksData.Range("A2:A5").Copy
ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial
Set MyShape = ppSlide.Shapes(ppSlide.Shapes.Count)

MyShape.Top = x
MyShape.Height = y
MyShape.Width = z
MyShape.Left = m
```

Now I Need something like MyShape.Align = Right (which of course is not working).
Can someone help me with this?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following procedure, it works on my Excel file.
You need to have an open PowerPoint, this sub-routine will scan column A in your Excel file (starting from the second row).
It will create a new slide at the end of the open PowerPoint, and will create a Table with the number of rows it found text in your Excel worksheet column A.
At last it will store each Excel's row data in in the new Table.

```
Sub Export_to_PPT_Table()

Dim wksData                As Excel.Worksheet
Dim PPT                    As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppslide                As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ppShape                As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim ppTable                As PowerPoint.Table

' in brackets add your worksheet name
Set wksData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
PPT.Visible = True

'Add a blank slide at the end of an existing PowerPoint
Set ppslide = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank)

Dim Excel_numofRows         As Integer
ExcelRow = 2
' loop through your excel file in Column A, and check for last row with existing text inside
While wksData.Cells(ExcelRow, 1) <> ""
    Excel_numofRows = ExcelRow
    ExcelRow = ExcelRow + 1
Wend

' create a new Table in the new slide created
' in brackets is where you play with your table's properties
Set ppShape = ppslide.Shapes.AddTable(Excel_numofRows, 1, 100, 100, PPT.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth - 300, 150)
Set ppTable = ppShape.Table

ExcelRow = 2
While wksData.Cells(ExcelRow, 1) <> ""
    With ppTable
        .Cell(ExcelRow - 1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = wksData.Cells(ExcelRow, 1)
        .Cell(ExcelRow - 1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentRight
        .Cell(ExcelRow - 1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    End With
    ExcelRow = ExcelRow + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but that´s not working :-(maybe because the shape is a table?

Comment: This code is working in my PowerPoint Slide, on a Table. Can you put here your entire code ? this way I will test it on my PowerPoint.